# Python: ¿Puedo poner mas de una definicion a una misma palabra en un direccionario?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo una prueba de un "chatbot", y almaceno todas las nuevas palabras en un diccionario llamado "words", y quiero que elija una definicion aleatoria de una palabra, pero primero, no se si eso se puede y si se puede no se como.

Codigo:

```
words = {"hola" : "Hey!"} # Aqui, quiero añadir mas definiciones

c = input("> ") # Con esto se pide la entrada de texto al usuario
if c in words:
   print(words[c])
```

Mi pregunta es como lo hago y como hago que elija una aleatoria entre todas ellas

Comment: si quieres añadir más definiciones utiliza una lista como valor de la clave y para escoger de forma aleatoria usa el modulo random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres asociar varios valores a una clave, entonces los almacenas en una lista:

```
words = {"hola" : ["Hey!", "Hi!", "Howdy!"]}
```

En este diccionario, la clave "hola" tiene asociada una lista de tres respuestas alternativas.

Si la palabra está en el diccionario, puedo recuperar la lista de respuestas (`saludos`) y seleccionar al azar un elemento. Para eso genero un valor aleatorio entre cero y el largo de la lista (`idx`) que será el indice de la respuesta seleccionada.

```
import random

c = input("> ") # Con esto se pide la entrada de texto al usuario
if c in words:
    saludos = words[c]
    idx = random.randint(0, len(saludos))
    print(saludos[idx])
```

Comment: tambien puedes usar `random.suffle` que escoge un elemento aleatorio de una lista

Comment: @Christian random.suffle le da un orden aleatorio a una secuencia. Si se quiere elegir un solo elemento aleatorio de una secuencia convendría más usar random.choice.